# save and retrieve sub-graphs using networkx and py2neo?

Tags: flask, neo4j, networkx, py2neo

I'm working with flask and neo4j.
Right now ,I developed the user management service with py2neo, and i want to save and retrieve subgraphs created with networkx.
so what is the best way to combine networkx and py2neo?

Comment: Are you willing to use IPython?

Comment: I don't know, I never used IPython before